# Google Maps iOS SDK Crash - GMSBackgroundAppException

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I have integrated Google Maps for iOS SDK into my app, and I am getting a strange crash.

```
FatalException: GMSBackgroundAppException
Background execution would crash in this scenario

0  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183abe59c __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1  libobjc.A.dylib                    0x00000001942080e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183abe4dc -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  myApp                               0x00000001004c4a04 -[GMSAsyncInitServices sharedInitWithSync:]
4  myApp                               0x00000001004c48d4 -[GMSAsyncInitServices initSync]
5  myApp                               0x00000001004c5588 +[GMSServices sharedServicesSync]
6  myApp                               0x00000001004ba4a8 -[GMSMapView sharedInitWithServices:camera:]
7  myApp                               0x00000001004b9e44 -[GMSMapView initWithFrame:camera:]
8  myApp                               0x00000001004b9cdc +[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:camera:]
9  myApp                               0x0000000100103c88 -[GoogleMapViewController viewDidLoad] (GoogleMapViewController.m:63)
10 UIKit                                  0x000000018826d184 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 692
11 UIKit                                  0x000000018826ce94 -[UIViewController view] + 32
12 myApp                               0x0000000100136cc0 -[BaseViewController viewDidLoad] (BaseViewController.m:93)
13 UIKit                                  0x000000018826d184 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 692
14 UIKit                                  0x000000018826ce94 -[UIViewController view] + 32
15 UIKit                                  0x000000018895e90c -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 76
16 UIKit                                  0x000000018856787c -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 120
17 UIKit                                  0x000000018858291c -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 1972
18 UIKit                                  0x000000018827ace8 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 88
19 UIKit                                  0x0000000188584dd8 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 284
20 UIKit                                  0x000000018835a3d4 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 216
21 myApp                               0x00000001000cf1e4 -[FirstViewController viewDidAppear:] (FirstViewController.m:49)
22 UIKit                                  0x000000018828418c -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 592
23 UIKit                                  0x00000001882ef5fc -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 64
24 UIKit                                  0x00000001882ef564 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 356
25 UIKit                                  0x0000000188260ea0 _afterCACommitHandler + 572
26 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183a76a50 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
27 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183a739dc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 360
28 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183a73dbc __CFRunLoopRun + 836
29 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001839a10a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
30 GraphicsServices               0x000000018cb3b5a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
31 UIKit                                  0x00000001882d2aa4 UIApplicationMain + 1488
32 myApp                               0x0000000100266818 main (main.m:16)
33 libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000194876a08 start + 4
```

There was a bug reported for a similar crash on the Google dev website, though I am not 100% sure if this is a Google bug, or some misuse of the SDK:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7716

BaseViewController is the main view of my app, and gets loaded when the app starts (or immediately after a register/login).  In it's viewDidLoad() method it initializes my GoogleMapViewController, which is just a UIViewController that holds the map.  The viewDidLoad() for the GoogleMapVC is here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

//We have to stop Google Maps from accessing location when the app goes into the background.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(appGoingBackground:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(appBecomeActive:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
self.allMarkers = [NSMutableArray array];


double latitude = 40.71448;
double longitude = -74.00598;

GPSManager *manager = [GPSManager sharedInstance];
if (manager.lastKnownLocation) {
    latitude = manager.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    longitude = manager.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.longitude;
}

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                        longitude:longitude
                                                             zoom:5];

self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
[self.mapView setMinZoom:1 maxZoom:15];
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
[self performSelector:@selector(setPadding) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

The line that is causing the crash is this one:

```
    self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
```

The title of the crash report would seem to indicate this has something to do with execution in the background, but as I said earlier, this is code that gets executed in viewDidLoad(), when the app starts up.

Is there something I am missing?  Any thoughts/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what causes the problem, but a better practice is to put addObserver code in the `viewDidAppear()` and remove the observers in `viewDidDisappear()`, so it will prevent your observers get added multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was fixed in the version 1.10.0, please check the release note :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases

Hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else runs into this, Google posted a response on their dev board.

This crash happens when the Google Map is instantiated while the app is in the background.  They suggested catching the exception in this case, and re-instantiating when the app returns to the foreground.

Here is the link to the Google dev board post in question:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7716

Comment: Could you please share the link to the post?